# Cygwin shell in VS Code tries to activate conda. How to prevent this?

Tags: windows-10, python, cygwin, visual-studio-code, anaconda

In my Windows 10 computer I have VS Code and Cygwin installed. I use Cygwin bash as the shell for VS Code. I also have the Anaconda Python distribution installed.

Whenever I open a new shell in VS Code, it tries to run

```
cd C:/path/to/a/folder/that/does/not/exist/
conda activate base
```

This obviously fail. But I do not care, because my shells work great as they are. I do **not** want to activate conda.

How I do I make my bash inside VS Code stop running those 2 commands?

EXTRA INFO:
This does no happen on normal Cygwin shells (outside VS Code)
This only happens for a new shell. The shell that opens as VS Code starts does not do this.

Comment: Check if Vscode has any anaconda extension or something. Also check if `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in cygwin home folder has any conda related commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4305

One needs to add

```
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false,
```

to `settings.json`